# How to find & replace many expressions with one in Vim?

Tags: vim, vi

I am copy-pasting an example from a PDF to Vim and I have to replace all `“` and `”` with `"`
and all `‘` and `’` with `'` so that the code works.

Well that will probably seem easier to understand:
I want to replace all `foo` and `bar` with `foobar` simultaneously.

Comment: PDF… outputted by PDFLaTeX with code verbatim sections I presume?

Comment: Probably. I don't have the latex code itself, just the pdf.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this in `vi`:

```
:1,$s/[“”]/"/g
```

then

```
:1,$s/[‘’]/'/g
```

Comment: Thanks. 
  
You could replace 1,$ with % .

How can I make it to work with hole words rather than characters ?

Comment: @Dimitar Slavchev: `:%s/\<\(foo\|bar\)\>/foobar/g` (see `:help pattern`) : `\<`…`\>` delimit a word and `\(`…`\|`…`\)` are an alternation (with capture here)

Answer (score 3):

Use tr as a filter:

Unix way:

```
:%!tr “”‘’ \"\"\'\'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to replace all "foo"s and all "bar"s with "foobar" you can use this:

`%s/\v<(foo|bar)>/foobar/g`

This will replace the "foo"s and the "bar"s but will leave any "foobar"s alone.

- `%s/` - substitute across the whole file
- `\v` - use very magic regex syntax (see `:help magic` for more info)
- `<` - match a left word boundary
- `(foo|bar)` - foo or bar
- `>` - match a right word boundary
- `/foobar/` - replacement string
- `g` - globally (will happen for every occurrence, not just the first on the line)

Note that if you are just dealing with punctuation you'll probably want to remove the word boundary parts of this regex or it won't work.